Cannot get x-Ticks to Change for .plot(kind='area')
I'm a recent learner of Python and Pandas and [enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/K5ml2mGy.jpg)created the pivot table shown in the attached image that has a set processing stages in order of priority on one axis and the age at which these processes occur in the life of the processing cycle on the other axis. I would attach the real data it has 386 rows.
I then create the area plot image attached that plots exactly as I'd like it too, but the X-Axis has only one tick. I have tried numerous methods to get the ticks to change and nothing works. This is the way I set rc parameters
rc = {'figure.figsize':(12,7),'axes.facecolor':'white','axes.grid' : True,'grid.color': '.8', 'font.family':'Times New Roman','font.size' : 12}

 plt.rcParams.update(rc)

The code that follows throws an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_xticks'
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}%'.format
StkPivTIDPct= StkPivotT.div(StkPivotT.iloc[:,-1], axis=0 )*100
StkPivTIDPctA= StkPivTIDPct.iloc[:, :-1]
StkPivTIDPctA.plot(kind='area')
plt.xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_xticks([0,10,20,20,40,50,60,70,80,90])
plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.legend(fontsize=12) # using a size in points
#plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.show()

The same error appears if I do this:
plt.xticks([0,10,20,20,40,50,60,70,80,90])
I have tried many other methods that I have seen online and am unsure what creates the problem and how to resolve it..  Thank you in advance for your kind attention
I tried the two methods detailed prior and many others:
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
plt.axes.Axes.set_xticks
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
.... Also - the plot does not relocate the legend when I send it code like plt.legend(loc="upper right") .. or respond to axis title settings and the like.

Did you try to restart your environment? You seem to have a variable called ax that is of type DataFrame instead of the expected matplotlib's Axes type.  You could try ax = plt.gca() to set ax to "the current ax".

Welcome to SO! For a proper [mre] please share code input data as text, nor image. Good tips in [ask]. And whatever seems to have redefined ax.

Much appreciated .. I have a lot to learn about ax ... axis
